# Facebook comment counter not working on home page of blog

Tags: blogger, facebook-comments

UPDATE: The old issue is fixed, and it was due to fb scraping issue and not blogger. But now another problem appeared. Here's the issue: After scraping all the post urls on fb debugger, I was able to see existing comments but the moment I make a new comment, again the total comment counter is becoming 0(both on home page and inside post). <strike>I've to manually scrape the url again on fb for the comment to appear.</strike>. The comment counts are returning back to normal after some time. Again, when another comment is made, it's going back to 0 for some time. Whys's this happening? Is this issue from my side or facebook issue? Can somebody please test and inform?

I'm trying to replace the default blogger comment counter with Facebook comment counter as I've implemented Facebook comment plugin on the blog. This is what I've done.

There's three instances of the following code in the template.

```
<span class='post-comment-link'>
<b:if cond='data:blog.pageType != &quot;static_page&quot;'>
<b:if cond='data:post.allowComments'>
&amp;nbsp; <i class='fa fa-comment-o'/> <b:include data='post' name='comment_count_picker'/>
</b:if>
</b:if>
</span>
```

The second one is related to comment counter inside a post(near published date etc). When i replace that code with the following comment counter code, I can see total comments under the post title (as expected)

```
<b:if cond='data:post.isFirstPost'>   
<script>(function(d){
 var js, id = &#39;facebook-jssdk&#39;; if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
 js = d.createElement(&#39;script&#39;); js.id = id; js.async = true;
 js.src = &quot;//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&quot;;
 d.getElementsByTagName(&#39;head&#39;)[0].appendChild(js);
}(document));</script>
</b:if>
<a expr:href='data:post.url + &quot;#fb-root&quot;'><fb:comments-count expr:href='data:post.canonicalUrl'/> comments</a>
```

But the problem is that when I replace the third instance of the comment code (which is related to the comment counter in the home page) with the above code, I'm seeing "0 comments" in all posts. I want a working comment counter on both home page(under every post) and inside all posts. What am I doing wrong? How can I make it working?

Comment: Could you share your blog URL where you facing this issue?

Comment: Problem fixed Prayag. The issue was with Facebook, not with blogger. Facebook takes some time to scrape the url again so the comments were not appearing on time. After scraping manually by using the debugging tool, comments are visible both on home page and inside posts. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: Another issue appeared. After scraping all the post urls on fb debugger, I was able to see existing comments but the moment I make a new comment, again it's becoming 0(both on home page and inside post). I've to manually scrape the url again on fb for the comment to appear. Any idea?